# JSoup Selector internal text

Tags: java, css, jsoup

I need to get " Text Here" and not "Paragraph" only using selectors
How do i do it only using selector for JSoup?

```
<div>
   Text Here
   <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get the requested element using "getElemntById()". Here is an example:

```
String html="<html><body><div id='div1'>Text Here<p>Paragraph</p></div></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element div = doc.getElementById("div1");
String str = div.ownText();

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I need it with selectors only like div.div1

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<div>Text Here<p>Paragraph</p></div>");

    Element elem = document.select("div p").first();
    String text = elem.text();

    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Output

```
Paragraph
```